# Postman nested variables not parsed in when get environment variable in Pre-Request script

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

Imagine following environment variables:

- `Base-URL` => `https://my.website.com/api`
- `Cars-URL` => `{{Base-URL}}/cars`
- `Auth-URL` => `{{Base-URL}}/login`

If I use `GET {{Cars-URL}}` in postman it works fine and it does a call to `https://mu.website.com/api/cars`

Same applies for `POST {{Auth-URL}}` it works perfectly and I retrieve a JWT token.

However I would like to use Pre-Request Scripts of my collection to automatically fetch the JWT token before any call in the collection. Therefore I use the following setup:

```js
var authUrl = pm.environment.get("Auth-URL");

pm.sendRequest({
    url: authUrl,
    method: "POST",
    header: { ... },
    body: { ... },
    function (err, res) {
        pm.environment.set("JWT-token", res)
    }
});
```

I get the following output in my console:

```
POST http://{{base-url}}/login
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND {{base-url}}
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.5
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Host: {{base-url}}
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

It seems like that `pm.environment.get` does not parse the nested variable.

**How to fix this issue?**

Comment: Where is `base-url` coming from? In your example you have `Base-URL` as the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pm.variables.replaceIn` (available since **v7.6.0**.)

This will do the trick:

```js
var authUrl = pm.variables.replaceIn(pm.environment.get("Auth-URL"));

pm.sendRequest({
   ....
})
```

Comment: That method should work like this and that was only really implemented to substitute the string values and allow you to use the `{{..}}` syntax in the scripts. `pm.variables.replaceIn("{{Auth-URL}}")`